# Excel VBA - Save As Dialog Window - stop code from continuing if "cancel" is pressed?

Tags: vba, excel

I currently use the following code to force the user to save the file as a macro enabled workbook.

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show , xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

The problem is, if the user presses the "Cancel" button, the code continues on. I need to it to stop if the "Cancel" button is pressed.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This page has a nice example that explains what you need to do:

http://codevba.com/excel/dialogs.htm#SaveAs

Essentially, it's like this:

```
' Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show returns
' True or False depending on whether the user canceled or not
If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show Then
   ' User saved
Else
   ' User canceled
End If
```

Taking a more complete example from the link above and modifying it slightly to your purposes:

```
Sub thing()

Dim strFilename As String: strFilename = "report1"
Dim strFolder As String: strFolder = "C:\temp\" 'initial directory - NOTE: Only works if file has not yet been saved!

'Dim xlfFileFormat As XlFileFormat: xlfFileFormat = XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook 'or replace by other XlFileFormat
Dim xlfFileFormat As XlFileFormat: xlfFileFormat = XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled 'or replace by other XlFileFormat

Dim strPassword As String: 'strPassword = "password" 'The password with which to protect the file - if any
Dim booBackup As Boolean: 'booBackup = True  '(Whether to create a backup of the file.)
Dim strWriteReservationPassword As String: 'strWriteReservationPassword = "password2" ' (The write-reservation password of the file.)
Dim booReadOnlyRecommendation As Boolean: booReadOnlyRecommendation = False '(Whether to recommend to the user that the file be opened in read-only mode.)
Dim booWorkbookSaved As Boolean ' true if file saved, false if dialog canceled
If Len(strFolder) > 0 Then ChDir strFolder
booWorkbookSaved = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(Arg1:=strFilename, Arg2:=xlfFileFormat, Arg3:=strPassword, _
                                            Arg4:=booBackup, Arg5:=strWriteReservationPassword, Arg6:=booReadOnlyRecommendation)

If Not booWorkbookSaved Then
    Exit Sub
End If

MsgBox "Workbook saved"

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that, but there are two issues: 1. It doesn't automatically choose a macro enabled workbook 2. The code continues on if the user presses the cancel button, which is my biggest issue here. I've been trying for several hours and I just can't seem to get it to work (I have tried probably half a dozen code structures).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to capture the event when the cancel button is clicked.

```
Sub saveasxml()
Dim userResponce As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
 userResponce = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show("Test name", 52)
On Error GoTo 0
If userResponce = False Then
    MsgBox "Cancel clicked"
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "You saved file "
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this works - only thing is I would like the current file name to show up in the save as box instead of "Test Name" - is there a way to do this?

Comment: Put the current file name into a variable and replace "test name" with the variable.